# Ubuntu One: Publish file option available in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: ubuntu-one, firefox, google-chrome

Is this a known bug?  I can publish an Ubuntu One file or folder in Firefox, but that option under the "More" button isn't available in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

There was a small problem yesterday which should be resolved now. If you log out of the site, and then log back in, it should reappear.